# RegEx to remove all control / invisible characters EXCEPT CR or LF

Tags: .net, regex, unicode

I am trying to use regex (.Net) to "sanitize" a Unicode input string -- the requirement is to remove all invisible characters / control characters EXCEPT CR (carriage returns) and LF (linefeeds).  In other words, keep all valid printable characters (English and French) including CR and LF.

I have tried the following (just using the underscore to see what was replaced), but it also removes CR / LF ...

```
clean_str = Regex.Replace( in_str, "\p{C}+", "_" )
```

Also tried:

```
clean_str = Regex.Replace( in_str, "(\p{Cf}|\p{Co}|\p{Cs}|\p{Cn}|[\x00-\x09]|\x0b|\x0c|[\x0e-\x1f]|\x7f)+", "_" )
```

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html ...

```
p{C} or \p{Other}: invisible control characters and unused code points.

 ◦\p{Cc} or \p{Control}: an ASCII 0x00–0x1F or Latin-1 0x80–0x9F control character.
 ◦\p{Cf} or \p{Format}: invisible formatting indicator.
 ◦\p{Co} or \p{Private_Use}: any code point reserved for private use.
 ◦\p{Cs} or \p{Surrogate}: one half of a surrogate pair in UTF-16 encoding.
 ◦\p{Cn} or \p{Unassigned}: any code point to which no character has been assigned.
```

Guru's - if you have a better / more efficient way -- please post !

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use character class subtraction to exclude CR and LF from the control character class:

```
clean_str = Regex.Replace( in_str, "[\p{C}-[\r\n]]+", "" )
```

Comment: Sorry -- does not work with strings that contain brackets or other special printable characters -- i.e.: [ ] ..

Comment: Yes -- that will work as well -- thanks!   Wondering which would be quicker -- the Regex.Replace() or iterate through the string ?

Comment: That's a good question, while I suspect that the regex code would be faster, I think the only way to know for certain would be to benchmark them on strings of various lengths.

Comment: Correct - but in order to run a valid test -- I would need to know what the {C} character class is made up of (in order to build the equivalent case statement).   Could not find anything in the Microsoft docs at:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories  --  so for the time being, I am using the regex expression.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm browsing through it appears there are quite a few characters in the Cx groups

Comment: Here is a unicode text file with the control characters: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using `RegEx`, you could just iterate the string:

```cs
public string Clean(string dirty)
{
    var clean = new StringBuilder();
 
    const char SPACE = ' ';
    const char LF = '\n';
    const char CR = '\r';
    const char DEL = (char)127;

    foreach (var c in dirty)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case CR or LF:
                clean.Append(c);
                break;

            case <= SPACE or DEL:
                continue;

            default:
                clean.Append(c);
                break;
        }
    }

    return clean.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Probably the easiest -- but what about ASCII 127 (DEL) -- codes like this are not printable?  I know -- add the code to the case statement ...

Comment: I've replaced the pseudo-code with working C# now, @bdcoder. It takes `DEL` into consideration.